# Ionic - amcharts4 - Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, amcharts4

after an update of packages began to throw the error. I tried rolling back the update but the error continues.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nexus-pwa",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.7.10",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.11.5",
    "core-js": "^3.4.1",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ngx-spinner": "^8.0.3",
    "npm-check-updates": "^3.2.1",
    "ol": "^6.1.1",
    "point-in-polygon": "^1.0.1",
    "robust-point-in-polygon": "^1.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.4.0",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.803.19",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.19",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.3.19",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.3.19",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.19",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~12.12.11",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.5.2",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

graph-detail.page.html:

```
<div #chartElement ></div>
```

graph-detail.page.ts

```
import * as am4charts from '@amcharts/amcharts4/charts';
import * as am4core from '@amcharts/amcharts4/core';
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-graph-detail',
  templateUrl: './graph-detail.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graph-detail.page.scss'],
})
export class GraphDetailPage implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('chartElement', { static: false }) chartElement;

  constructor(
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.createGraph();
  }

  createGraph()
  {
    const chart = am4core.create(this.chartElement.nativeElement, am4charts.XYChart);
  }
}
```

ERROR:

```
tslib.es6.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at Module.__extends (tslib.es6.js:25)
    at Label.js:62
    at Module../node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/elements/Label.js (Label.js:1345)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/System.js (System.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/utils/Animation.js (Animation.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/Sprite.js (Sprite.js:1)
```

The error is at runtime, the compilation is successful.
If I delete "this.createGraph();", the error continues.
If I delete the am4core.create line, the error disappears.

I tried cleaning the node_modules folder and reinstalling all the packages.
Clearing the cache with "npm cache clean" and nothing.

Any ideas? Thanks

**UPDATE:**

The problem is in the amcharts4 library version, since version 4.7.9 it starts to fail.

Using version 4.7.8 works correctly for the package configuration detailed above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the below command for building the application

**For Angular**

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false
```

**For Ionic**

```
ionic build --prod --build-optimizer=false
```

or else you have to add this syntax in package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false"
}
```

Comment: Hi Miyas, I tried that way but throw the same error.

Comment: @Matías I tried below example in a new project which seems to be working fine please check the below link: `https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/integrations/using-angular2/`

Comment: I have an example with angular working, the problem is with the ionic project.

Comment: Even i also tried the above example in ionic project which works fine. graph is working by using `npm start` command.

Comment: It worked for me using amchart4 version 4.7.8, since version 4.7.9 it starts to fail. Thanks Miyas.